# How to pass an image to custom listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I am designing a custom `ListView` in my android app, and i have my custom list item containing an `ImageView` and a`TextView`

I have the following class

```
public class Language {
    private int id;
    private String languageName;
}
```

And a `List<Language> languages;`

Now what I want to do is to load drawable image for each language item, and then display the list in my listview. So far I have done the following

```
String[] from = new String[]{"item_logo", "item_name"}; //mapping
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.li_logo, R.id.li_name}; //first one is id of my imageview
//the second one is id of my textview

List<HashMap<String, Object>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<>();

for (Language language : languages) {
       HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
       map.put("item_logo", getImage(language.getId()));
       map.put("item_name", language.getLanguageName());
       fillMaps.add(map);
}

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_languages);

 SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.list_item, from, to);
```

the getImage method loads an image from web service as a byte array, and then converts it to drawable, but the listview doesn't show it.

Also, i've found that if i replace the method call with a local drawable id, the list starts to show the drawable.

So my question is, if i have a byte array representing an image, how can i pass it to the listview, so that it starts to show it.

P.S. also here's how my getImage method converts byte array to drawable and returns

```
drawable = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(logoBlob, 0, logoBlob.length));
return drawable;
```

Comment: You need to put it in a BitmapDrawable probably. I would also look into using a image library like Picasso.

Comment: just updated my question. As you can see, my drawable is already a BitmapDrawable, so i guess i have to try something else